# priority rule between sent and receive operation in a go select statement

Tags: go, select, channel

Is there a priority rule between sent and receive operation in a go select statement ?

Since a "send" operation is always ready, not like a "receive" operation that wait for something to come from the channel, I always have the feeling that the "send" will be executed first on a select.

I tried a little code to test what happens when both send and receive are ready:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan string)
    ch2 := make(chan string)
    go goOne(ch1)
    go goTwo(ch2)

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    select {
    case ch2 <- "To goTwo goroutine":
    case msg1 := <-ch1:
        fmt.Println(msg1)
    }
}

func goOne(ch chan string) {
    ch <- "From goOne goroutine"
}

func goTwo(ch chan string) {
    msg := <-ch
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
```

The result seems to always be "From goOne goroutine". So it seems the receive operation has the priority.
But is it by design effect ? Or could it happen that the sent got executed first? I couldn't find the info in the doc

If I want the receive operation to have the priority, can I rely on that or should I do something else ?

Thanks!

Comment: A send is not always ready, it can block just the same as a receive. There is no priority, from [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Select_statements): _`If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection`_

Comment: Also note that this example will pick either case randomly, but there is no coordination with the print statement in `goTwo`, so you probably won't see any output before the program exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a priority rule between sent and receive operation in a go select statement?

No. When more than one `case` is ready at the same time, one at random is executed.

> Since a "send" operation is always ready

Not true. A send operation may just block (i.e. not ready) when nothing is receiving on the other side, or when a buffered channel's buffer is full.

> Or could it happen that the sent got executed first?

Yes, but you may see no output when this case is selected because your program resumes execution in main and exits immediately before the `goTwo` goroutine can actually print anything.

> If I want the receive operation to have the priority [...]

The very *semantics* of a select statement are: "execute whichever is ready first". If one case must have priority over the other, change the other one to `default` (runs if nothing else is ready):

```
    select {
    case msg1 := <-ch1:
        fmt.Println(msg1)
    default:
        ch2 <- "To goTwo goroutine"
    }
```